# Significant figures and accuracy

Tags: experimental-chemistry, significant-figures

A sample was weighed using two different balances. The results were $\pu{(a) 4.929 g and (b) 5.0 g}$. How would the mass of the sample be reported?

**Method 1**
$$ \text{Average of the values} =\frac{4.929 + 5.0}{2}= \frac{9.9}{2}$$ (the result of addition can have only one digit after decimal as in 5.0) $$\pu{= 4.95= 5.0 g}$$ (the result of division can contain only one digit after decimal as in 9.9)

Hence, the mass of the sample is to be reported as $\pu{5.0g}$.

**Method 2**

Out of the two values, 4.929 is more accurate and will be reported as 4.9 after rounding off.

Hence, the mass of the sample is to be reported as $\pu{4.9 g}$.

Which of the above method is correct?

Comment: The first method. You might want to check out [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision) Wiki, which highlights the difference between accuracy and precision.

Comment: Mods, this goes to phy SE right?

Comment: In method 1 the reported answer should be 5.0 g, not 5 g.

Comment: @HahaHahaha I feel such basic concepts are to be known by anyone who aspires to pursue science in their academic career in future. Actually there are few cases where the line between different branches of science seem to fade. I feel this can stay, rest is up to the moderators.

Answer (score 4):

Both method 1 and method 2 are wrong. The concept of useless significant figures should be wiped out from school curricula and replaced with proper statistics. This significant figures and concept of estimation was good for the 18th century when eye-balling and manual measurements had to be made. The concept originated in the 16th century.

In method 1: If you are using an electronic balance and weighed your object, the display reads 4.929g, this is what you will record. No data should be rounded off until the end of the calculations. **Data should be recorded as it is without manipulating it.**

The "true" error of balance will *never ever* be estimated by the so-called significant figure rules. We will check the precision by repeatedly weighing the object and we will check the accuracy by using a known weight. The "constant" error in the balance if it existed, will be corrected either by subtraction or addition.

In method 2, I am not aware of any scientific balance which will measure only one decimal place, even if it does, an accurately calibrated balance will read the weight as 4.9 g not 5.0 g. If it is reading it as 5.0 g, there is a huge error in either balance 1 or balance 2.

You see we never needed to invoke significant figures here.

Comment: Interesting perspective. Why are significant figures still taught in school curricula in that case? And when do people realize that this method is not accurate? (I'm guessing when they do serious lab work, please confirm)

Comment: I think this is just traditional and perhaps to teach common sense that we should not report concentration to 9 decimal places. However, the problem arises when some teachers start teaching significant figures as scientific facts or a part of some holy book and "this is the only way". Nobody has taught them to think critically ---they simply pass it on to their poor students who just cannot make sense out of it.

Comment: The experimental way, is the way, most scientists will do it.